# Any Drawback on running setup:upgrade, di:compile, static deploy everytime code level edit on Magento 2

Tags: cache, permissions, setup-upgrade, static-content-deploy, setup-di-compile

Is it ok to run the following set of commands by default everytime I make a code level edit (layout edits, module creation, extension update)

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

I believe that not all edits require, setup upgrade or di:compile.
But, does running all above set of commands even if not required cause any issue.

EDIT: Should not use 777

```
chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/
```

Comment: what mode you are using ?

Comment: the only problem you will face is when magento regenerate those new files then again you need to setup permission after running these commands since you will no longer own those files

Comment: @Pawan default. (if you are asking for setup deploy.. yes, its not required in default mode, but asking if any issue, if i run all of them)

Comment: @Chikku hmm.. so I should also include the ownership command at the end?

Comment: yep thats right

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we don't need to run every command all the time. Sometimes it only requires cache: flush but extension creation or enabling any extension needs every command.
Not an issue if you're running these command unnecessarily except changing permission, but It's wasting of time, and mainly if the site is live, then it stops working until commands executed.
While in chmod command, it grants permission, so it's recommended not to use that command without requirement because every permission setting of a file is for security purpose.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. is the following proper? [code]find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento[/code]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you check out the documentation on each of the commands or just run

```
php bin/magento help
```

to see a list of available cli commands and their purposes. Depending on the mode you are using for your installation you might not require to run anything other than

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

most of the time. If you change any di.xml file, run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and if you are not in developer mode, changes to *.html and *.js files will require

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

to take effect.
Should not be required at all after running it once - at least when your webserver's user configuration is correct:

```
chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/
```

Especially di.xml compilation and static content deploy can take quite some time on a dev machine, so better not run them if it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes, commands required to be run depend on the changes made in Magento. But, I'm asking is there any issue if I run all the commands anyhow everytime..